# Record Sharing Using Apex

Tags: apex

Can anyone give me the code for following scenario:
        write sharing code on the object(object name=test and fields are email,phone) so that the record will be shared to all the managers in the hierarchy. For eg, Gowtham's manager is Prabu and Prabu's Manager is Raja. In this case whichever record gowtham create should be shared to Prabu and Raja.

If there is one more employee and his manager is just gopi then whatever record that employee creates should be shared to gopi. Raja, Prabu and gowtham should not see the record

Please Help!

Comment: Have you ever tried something ? We can help you to improve your code, not to do it !

Comment: This may be of some help: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm